# How to export (bacpac) azure database

Tags: export, azure-sql-database, ssms, bacpac, azure-data-sync

I have one database in azure and accessing in my SQL Server Management studio and try to export the database but gives me the errors.

Here are the steps I have done:

1) Export data-tier Application

[image]

2) No of errors I got

[image]

3) Got this error in all the processes:

[image]

I am using SSMS (2014 and 2016)

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio in order to have the best user experience with Azure SQL Database. Please download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

That dss schema means you were using SQL Data Sync. You may need to use the deprovision utility to clean that remnants left by SQL data Sync.

Alternatively you can use SQLpackage, PowerShell or Azure Portal to do the same task. You can learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export#export-to-a-bacpac-file-using-the-sqlpackage-utility).

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:Export /tf:testExport.bacpac /scs:"Data Source=apptestserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=MyDB;" /ua:True /tid:"apptest.onmicrosoft.com"
```